# File to dictionary, cannot get program to run

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, indexing

So I am trying to write a piece of code to take text from a file, move into a dictionary and then process it. I keep getting this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Oghosa\Assignment2.py", line 12, in <module>
builtins.IndexError: string index out of range
```

Here's my program:

```
endofprogram = False
dic = {}
try:
    filename = input("Please Enter the Filename:")
    infile = open(filename, 'r')
except IOError:
    print("Error Reading File! Program ends here!")
    endofprogram = True
if endofprogram == False:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip("\n")
        if (line != " ") and (line[0] != "#"):
            item = line.split(":")
            print(items)
            dic["Animal id"] = item[0]
            dic["Date"] = item[1]
            dic["Station"] = item[2]
        print(dic)
```

Can someone aid in pointing out my mistake please?

Here's a sample input text:

```
#Comments
a01:01-24-2011:s1
a03:01-24-2011:s2
  <blank line>
  <blank line>
a02:01-24-2011:s2
a03:02-02-2011:s2
a03:03-02-2011:s1
a02:04-19-2011:s2
  <blank line>
#comments
a01:05-14-2011:s2
a02:06-11-2011:s2
a03:07-12-2011:s1
a01:08-19-2011:s1
a03:09-19-2011:s1
a03:10-19-2011:s2
a03:11-19-2011:s1
a03:12-19-2011:s2
```

Comment: Can you give us an input file sample?

Comment: @Christian Here is one called animallog.txt

Comment: Don't post it as a comment, edit your post and put it there. Make sure it is correctly formatted.

Comment: Your big issue is when a line is blank line, the only char that line has inside is "\n" and then you do line = line.strip("\n") and the result of this is line = "" then you try to do if (line != " ") and (line[0] != "#")... but line = "" so line is not " " (blankspace) and when the program try to do (line[0] != "#") it fails because line is a empty string and if you try to access position 0 of an empty string you get the error string index out of range

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a blank line in your file?  On line 12 you may want to check that the line has text before indexing it using `line[0]`.  Do you really have a line with an empty string of should line 12 really read:

```
if line.strip() and (line[0] != "#"):
```

Edit.. Adding a full example.

```
dic = {}
filename = input("Please Enter the Filename:")
try:
    infile = open(filename, 'r')
except IOError:
    print("Error Reading File! Program ends here!")
else:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        if line and line[0] != "#":
            item = line.split(":")
            dic["Animal id"] = item[0]
            dic["Date"] = item[1]
            dic["Station"] = item[2]
```

Comment: There are empty strings in there, 3 to be exact. I have specified them in the orginal post. Thanks

Comment: I modified my answer to string the whitespace before the truthy check.

Comment: Thank you. That fixed it, Can I ask why my previous code didnt work>

Comment: I believe you hit a blank line.  In your original code you said that you wanted any line that wasn't just a space and didn't start with a #. A blank line would pass the first condition, but since there are no characters in a blank line `line[0]` raises an IndexError.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should at least print the offending line so you know what the culprit is:

```
for line in infile:
    items = line.strip("\n")
    try:
        if (line.strip != "") and (items[0] != "#"):
            items = line.split(":") #i dont like your reuse of line so changing to items
            ....
    except IndexError: #if python 3 use except IndexError as e:
        print(items) #prints offending line
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    endofprogram = False
    attrs=["Animal id","Date","Station"]
    dictionary=[]
    try:
        # filename = input("Please Enter the Filename:")   
        infile = open('rite.txt', 'r')
    except IOError:
        print("Error Reading File! Program ends here!")
        endofprogram = True 
    if endofprogram == False:    
        for line in infile:
            line = line.strip("\n")

            if (line != "") and (line[0] != "#"):
                item = line.split(":")
                dictionary.append(dict(zip(attrs, item)))
    print dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when there are blank lines in the file, `line[0]` doesn't exist. To fix this problem try this version:

```
endofprogram = False
dic = {}
try:
    filename = input("Please Enter the Filename:")
    infile = open(filename, 'r')
except IOError:
    print("Error Reading File! Program ends here!")
    endofprogram = True
if endofprogram == False:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip("\n")
        if len(line):
            if line[0] != "#":
                item = line.split(":")
                print(items)
                dic["Animal id"] = item[0]
                dic["Date"] = item[1]
                dic["Station"] = item[2]
            print(dic)
```

Also worth noting is that you are overwriting `dic` on each iteration of the loop. So after the loop is done; `dic` will only contain information from the last line of the file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you weren't checking for empty lines correctly in the

```
    if (line != " ") and (line[0] != "#"):
```

statement. This is because they wouldn't even have a space left in them after `line = line.strip("\n")` executed, so just about any indexing operation will fail.

The code below has that and several other coding errors fixed. Note it's important to post your actual code here to make it easier for people to help you.

```
endofprogram = False
dic = {}
try:
    filename = input("Please Enter the Filename:")
    infile = open(filename, 'r')
except IOError:
    print("Error Reading File! Program ends here!")
    endofprogram = True
if not endofprogram:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip("\n")
        if line and line[0] != "#":
            items = line.split(":")
            print(items)
            dic["Animal id"] = items[0]
            dic["Date"] = items[1]
            dic["Station"] = items[2]
    print(dic)
```